# Plot marker with formatter

Tags: highcharts

Am working on a project where i need to display the temperature level each month.

My doubt is, Is there any way to plot a custom marker for the series Tokyo.

The series is already there.

I need to show a custom marker like a small image or something.

```
My code:-

$(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'°'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 4,
                    lineColor: red,
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {

                }
            }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

        }
    },function(chart){

        setTimeout(function(){
                chart.series[1].data[0].graphic.attr({
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50
                });
            }, 1)

    });
});
```

Please help

Comment: Can you show an example? I mean, setting `line: { marker: { enabled: true } }` should do the thing, unless you specify "where labels are shown".

Comment: The actual question is unclear. What are you trying to do that isn't working?